# Fixed Points of Mappings.

Tags: functional-analysis

How do I find the fixed points of the following mappings?.

1. $\phi:\mathbb{R}\hookleftarrow, \phi(t)=t^3$, and
2. $T:C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\hookleftarrow, (T\psi)(t)={\psi}'(t)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ***(1)***, we have that $s \in \Bbb R$ is a fixed point of $\phi$ if and only if

$s^3 = \phi (s)  = s, \tag 1$

whence

$s^3 = s, \tag 2$

or

$s(s + 1)(s - 1) = s(s^2 - 1) = s^3 -s = 0, \tag 3$

forcing

$s \in \{ -1, 0, 1 \}; \tag 4$

that each of these three $s$-values is a fixed point of $\phi$ is easily verified.

As for ***(2)***, a fixed point of $T$ must satisfy

$\dfrac{d\psi(t)}{dt} = \psi'(t) = (T\psi)(t) = \psi(t); \tag 5$

if there exists $t_0 \in \Bbb R$ with $\psi(t_0) \ne 0$ then, since $\psi(t) \in C^\infty(\Bbb R)$, we have $\psi(t) \ne 0$ in some neighborhood $I$ of $t_0$ and we may write

$\dfrac{d \ln \psi(t)}{dt} = \dfrac{\psi'(t)}{\psi(t)} = 1, \; t \in I, \tag 6$

and hence

$\ln \left ( \dfrac{\psi(t)}{\psi(t_0)} \right )= \ln \psi(t) - \ln \psi(t_0) = \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t \dfrac{d \ln \psi(s)}{ds}\; ds = \int_{t_0}^t 1 \; ds = t - t_0, \tag 7$

that is,

$\psi(t) = \psi(t_0) e^{t - t_0}, \; t \in I; \tag 8$

though we have developed (8) under the assumption $t \in I$, we see that it is easily extends through to all of $\Bbb R$, and that it is indeed a fixed point of $T$ in this case.  $OE\Delta$.

Comment: @Stiven:  you are most welcome.  I assume you are aware that, if you really like an answer, you can "accept" it as a way of rewarding the "answerer"; just sayin' . . . Cheers!

Comment: Friend, would you help me with these exercises?.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950874/banach-fixed-point
and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950803/integral-linear-equation-of-fredholm
Please...

Comment: How do I prove that it has a unique solution in the linear integral equation of fredholm?, or would it be good to try it by oneness?.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950803/integral-linear-equation-of-fredholm

Comment: @Stiven: working on Fredholm.  Will keep you "posted"! 

Answer (score 0):

Writing out the functions explicitly, you get a polynomial equation and an ODE, respectively.

Can you solve them?

Comment: I tried, and I can not solve it.