# Integral linear equation of Fredholm.

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

How can I prove?.

Prove that if $[(b-a)|\lambda|sup_{t,s \in [a,b]}|\kappa (t,s)|]<1$, then a integral linear equation of Fredholm has a unique solution in $C[a,b]$.

We know by definition that; *in a integral equation of fredholm $K(t,s,u)=\lambda \kappa(t,s)u, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, we obtain the integral linear equation of fredholm $\psi (t)= \lambda \int _{a} ^b \kappa (t,s) \psi(s) ds + \varphi(t), t\in [a,b]$*.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts?